# Why can't I upgrade libgranite5 in the AppCenter?

Tags: appcenter, release-odin, error

I've just downloaded the new Elementary Os software version, and the app center is requesting to upgrade libgranite5, but it keeps going through this error:

Error while installing package: trying to overwrite '/usr/share/metainfo/granite.appdata.xml', which is also in the package libgranite-common 6.1.0+r2071+pkg119~ubuntu6.1

Is it possible to fix this? I'm a new user of Elementary Os and Linux, so I don't know much about those kind of stuff...

Comment: oh man, I'm also new to linux and eOS, kinda was expecting to see a solution, everytime I try to install something the same library shows up, and all the solutions require me to install that same libray. Some vicious cicle stuff

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?... this bug is killing me!

Comment: Did you add a custom PPA by any change? Any change this is similar to: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/29226/dependency-problem-with-libgranite ?